# Which one is faster view or subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, view, subquery

The question says it all. Which one is faster? And when should we use view instead subquery and vice verse when it comes to speed optimisation?

I do not have a certain situation but was thinking about that while trying some stuff with views in mysql.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither are particularly efficient in MySQL. In any case, MySQL does no caching of data in views, so the view simply adds another step in query execution. This makes views slower than subqueries. Check out [this blog post](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/12/mysql-view-as-performance-troublemaker/) for some extra info.

One possible alternative (if you can deal with slightly outdated data) is materialized views. Check out [Flexviews](http://code.google.com/p/flexviews/) for more info and an implementation.

Comment: Anybody know if this has changed since 2007?

Comment: @CharlesWood It's possible the specific performance problem referenced in the blog post I linked has been addressed, but I don't see any reason for views to be faster. Your best bet is always to benchmark it and see for yourself in your specific use case.

Answer (score 6):

A smart optimizer will come up with the same execution plan either way.  But *if* there were to be a difference, it would be because the optimizer was for some reason not able to correctly predict how the view would behave, meaning a subquery might, in some circumstances, have an edge.

But that's beside the point; this is a *correctness* issue.  Views and subquerys serve different purposes.  You use views to provide code re-use or security. Reaching for a subquery when you should use a view without understanding the security and maintenance implications is folly.  *Correctness trumps performance.*

Comment: I see. So basically speed wise they are the same?

Comment: Thank you Joel. I know about the different purposes of views and subqueries, but I wanted to know if there will be any speed gain if using one of them that the other.